# In training a classifier, what is it called when a human looks at the highest-confidence outputs and provides feedback on them iteratively?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

Say I have a unlabeled dataset, on which I am trying to train a classifier. It's costly to do labeling. So, I train a classifier $C_0$ on a small subset which I've labeled. Then I run it on some unlabeled data and have it output its predictions sorted by confidence. Then, a human scrolls down the list starting with the most confident prediction and labels the ones that are wrong. Say they do this for 3 predictions. We train a new classifier $C_1$ on the original training set plus the newly labeled examples. Repeat this process until the human is satisfied, producing a classifier $C_n$.

This is a terminology request: what is this process called in the literature?

Comment: I believe this is called [tag:active-learning], click on the tag to see some posts!